# Count last X cells from another sheet containing Y, as percentage

Tags: excel, excel-formula, countif

I have an overly complex Excel file that I have been using to track my progress learning golf. Specifically, I have a sheet that shows my average distance for the last *X* shots per club. The *X* is a drop down below the data table.

Sheet showing Shot Distribution with Quick Stats

[Data Table with dropdown](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rAUXB.png)

Currently, only the 'Avg. Yds' column changes based on the previous number selected from the drop down list. However, I would also like for the 'Left', 'Right', and 'Center' columns to adjust so that I can see if my accuracy is improving in relation to my distance. Currently, the Distribution columns are static and show the percentage of all shots inputted.

Recap: I am trying to work out a formula that calculates percentage of previous *X* shots that were *Left* of my target.

My formula for the Avg. Yds of my driver is

```
=AVERAGE(OFFSET(Table!B2,0,COUNT(Table!B2:VO2)-1,,-G27))
```

and seems to work fine.

My formula for the Distribution for Left of my driver is

```
=COUNTIF(Table!B3:VO3,"Left")/COUNTA(Table!B3:VO3)
```

but shows all inputted values from the *'Table'* sheet and not just the values from the last *X* shots.

As requested, here is a sample of the source data from the *Table* sheet:
[Source Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rBq0B.png)

Comment: It would help if you showed your source data table. Not the whole thing (heaven forbid), just (say) the first 12 rows.

Comment: (1) I don't see the drop down you refer to.... (2) Showing the formula bar would be useful (3) per @Spinner comment: I really don't feel like recreating so will come back to this if there is time remaining after addressing others who include something I can work off of that does not require recreating the template/table etc. (4) I don't really follow what you're trying to achieve (what is 'left' and 'right' in relation to - the tab or your shot or the 'X' I cannot see (why not simply reference the X in terms of which cell it is - given you've included row and column headers.

Comment: @JB-007: X is explained as 'the previous X shots' and (in context with the image) is the 'Number of most recent shots...'. From my POV the formulas and explanation suffice, but what's missing is data table for context. As an aside, I wasn't asking so you have to recreate, but for me and others, who may wish to better understand that context. :)

Comment: @Spinner - Glad it was clear to you - not at all clear to me (your explanation didn't help unfortunately - I'm referring to what is in the title, to the definition, to the final comment RE X in OPs q.  That's a fact (as it relates to my comprehension, no-one else's) that will not change regardless of how you have interpreted...  you should propose a solution if its clear to you.

Comment: @JB-007: My comment wasn't a 'quibble' as you put it. Was aiming to: clarify for you (sorry if it didn't help you); and (as your comment referred to mine) let Nathan know your comment wasn't a qualification or reflection of my POV (as I'd be happy to look closer based on what I asked). You already stated you're not, so not sure why you felt the need to restate that.

Comment: alright - you're right @Spinner.  whatever.  Pls leave me alone.

Comment: Thanks @Spinner, I have added a small sample of the source data from the applicable sheet.

Comment: @JB-007 - (1) I changed the table reference image to reflect the expanded dropdown list. (2) I can change the image again but thought copy/pasting the formula would be easier to view, if you'll tell me which formula you're wanting to see I'll add that the image. (3) (4) My average yard column changing based on the value in the drop down menu (i.e., what's my average distance of the last 10 shots). What I am trying to achieve is having the accuracy (Left, right, center) also change based on the drop down value. Currently is shows the overall accuracy from all data, not the most recent X shots.

Comment: What version of excel are you using? If you are using Excel 365, `FILTER` would let you easily get a list of all eg. 'Left' datapoints, and then you can use `SEQUENCE` and `FILTER` to get the last eg. 10 results.

Comment: Cheers @Nathan - nothing personal. Hope you didn't mind the 'side-quibbling' :) Looks like query potentially addressed below which is good to see...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two approaches are as shown below. In both cases, the formulas are for the same driver row as per your "My formula for the Distribution..." above
Using a COUNTIF approach the formula would be:

```
=COUNTIF(OFFSET(Table!B3,0,COUNTA(Table!B3:VO3)-1,,-G27),"Left")/G27
```

Alternately, you could use an array formula:

```
{=SUM(IF(OFFSET(Table!B3,0,COUNTA(Table!B3:VO3)-1,,-G27)="Left",1))/G27}
```

Both do the same thing, so use whichever you're most comfortable with.
*And I suspect after seeing these, you'll conclude the solution was staring at you the whole time*

Comment: Thank you! It frustrates me that I was sort of on the right path, but missed the goal. I'm appreciative of your help and this community.